# Dictionary values getting swapped

Tags: ios, json, swift, nsdictionary

I need to pass an input json as -

```
[{"QuestionId":77,"OptionId":297}]
```

However, when I do array.append(dict), the array that i get is with dictionaries containing key-value in the reversed order.

```
[["OptionId": 297, "QuestionId": 77]]
```

The "OptionId" and "QuestionId" seems to swap the position. Pls, can anyone rectify me from this issue.

I also need to pass a json as input parameter when calling webservice. I do it using alamofire. My json input is as - [{"QuestionId":77,"OptionId":297},{"QuestionId":78,"OptionId":304}]
How can i do this? 
I have tried with 
func callPostAnswersAPI(parameters: Array>) {

```
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://192.168.1.56/OnlineExamPortal/api/Question/PostAnswer")!)        
    request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted)
    let str = String(data: request.httpBody!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)      
    Alamofire.request(str!)
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)

                if let data = response.data, let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                    print(responseString)
                }
            case .success(let responseObject):
                print(responseObject)
            }
    }

}
```

at print(str!)I get the correct format of json, however after passing it to alamofire.request it adds backslashes. hence, the response enters .failure loop.
Am i following the correct procedure?

Comment: Dictionary values are not ordered, there is no swapping because there is no order.

Comment: thank you for the answer. What should I need to do in order to get the same order back?

Comment: Use a different data structure.

Comment: @Dyana If you want to keep the order, use any ordered collection, such as Arrays.

Comment: my json input paramater is an array of dictionaries.

Comment: Then just ignore the order in a Dictionary.

Comment: You need to use the dictionary keys in order to read dictionary elements in an ascending order with a number key.

Comment: You can always sort the array by the keys of the dictionary and then stick them back into the array. Sometimes you need dicts, sometimes you need arrays, depending on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: thank you @ElTomato . I have also added some extra concerns to the same question. Can you help me with that too?

Answer (score 1):

A JSON object is define in the JSON spec as an unordered collection.

> An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs.
>   (http://json.org/)

If order is important to you, then you should use a different collection type.

Comment: can you brief with an example. i am not sure how it needs to be handled. i am new to swift.

Answer (score 1):

From [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary):

> Every dictionary is an unordered collection of key-value pairs.

It has no order, so there is no swapping taking place.